# Porque no recibo los parametros que envio por axios en Django

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, cors

Estoy haciendo una consulta a mi api para lo cual envio datos de busqueda con axios pero en Django no estoy recibiendo esos parámetros.

```
  submit=(e)=>{
    const config={
    headers:{
      'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    }
      }
    const body=JSON.stringify({'parametro':document.getElementById("parametro").value}) 
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('/api/barrio',body,config)
    .then((res)=>console.log(res.data))
  }
```

Luego en Django cuando trato de imprimir el request.data no recibo nada

```
class BarriosViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BarrioSerializer
    queryset = Barrio.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data, args, kwargs)
```

Cuando hago el print, en consola me muestra objetos vacios.

Tengo los corsheaders configurado de la siguiente manera.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "webpack_loader",
    "backend.barrios",
    "frontend",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ("http://localhost:3000",)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]

**Actualización**
Cuando envio datos por postman, a través de body, si recibo los parámetros.
```

Comment: Tienes un problema de cors

Comment: @JackNavaRow hay alguna forma de comprobar si está funcionando correctamente el cors ?

Comment: [mira esta pagina](https://enable-cors.org/server.html), intenta cambiar el metodo en postman por *OPTIONS*

Comment: CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]

Comment: cambié get por OPTIONS en postman y de esa forma no recibo los parámetros,.. y probé también poniendo los cors_allowed_origins y tampoco